# How many internet protocols are there (related to domain/URL)?

Tags: networking, internet, http, domain, protocol

I need to know what are the protocols that are currently used (that can be related to domains or URLs and can be resolved by a DNS). Example:

```
www.domain.com
ftp.domain.com
ftps.domain.com
ftpes.domain.com
sftp.domain.com
pop.domain.com
pop3.domain.com
smtp.domain.com
imap.domain.com
```

I have searched the internet but could not find a complete list of these protocols. I appreciate any help

PD: the port used by the protocol or the application is not relevant for this question

Comment: Any relation between domain names and protocols is _entirely_ user-defined.

Comment: I think you’re confused about the presence of any relationship between protocol(s) running on a particular machine and its DNS name (“FQDN”). There is none. There are only some conventions such as www.domain.com to denote a web site for a particular domain but nothing is preventing you from running an FTP or Mail server from that same address.

Comment: @StarCat But an ftp can also be public and accessible from the internet and resolved by a DNS. And this is exactly what I need. Which protocols can be used publicly, which can be resolved by a DNS

Comment: DNS has nothing to do with the protocol(s) running on a server. DNS translates between a domain name and an IP address (and vice versa in the case of reverse DNS). It has no knowledge of any protocols and doesn’t need to.

Comment: @StarCat thanks. Maybe I have not done my question well, however I already fixed the problem. Thanks for your clarification

Comment: [More than you can shake a stick at](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/more-than-one-can-shake-a-stick-at)

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question. If you want to post a separate answer with the Wikipedia link you found useful, you are more than welcome to do that (though it's not clear that it answers the question you actually asked).

Comment: refererence wikipedia for more information. (Do not detele): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no relationship between a domain name and a protocol used by that domain name. One host that has a single domain name can speak multiple protocols (and usually does, at least all hosts have ssh in addition to whatever service their domain name might claim, because the administrator needs to access them somehow).

The protocols are connected to particular **port numbers** on a given host, although the assignment isn't so strict and with many services the port numbers may vary. But if we talk about standard assignment, then for example HTTP is port 80, HTTPS (secure variant) is 443. FTP is port 21 and more dynamically assigned ports during the FTP session. SMTP is port 25 for mail incoming to the server, or port 587 for mail submitted by mail client to be sent out by the server. IMAP is port 143, while IMAPS (secure variant, with encryption, used almost exclusively now) is port 993.

If you are looking for a list of protocol names, you can find a quite extensive list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

If we are talking about URL prefixes like `http:` or `mailto:`, they are yet another thing. Some of them like `http:`, `https:` or `ftp:` actually correspond to the protocol used to fetch the data. But others just tell how (or by what software) the URL should be handled. For example `mailto:` just means "fire up the mail client application and let it open the new message window with the recipient's email address given after `mailto:`". If you have a calendar application, it will recognize `webcal:` URLs, which are basically just HTTP, but the `webcal:` prefix indicates they should be handled by calendar application and not by the browser. `file:` just opens a local file with the given pathname, you can't call it a protocol :). If you have for example Zoom installed, it will handle the URLs starting with `zoommtg:` and connect to a meeting whose details are given after the `zoommtg:` prefix. So it all depends on the software you have installed and it's configuration. There is no complete list as you can always extend it by installing a new application that responds to some `anythingyoumaychoose:` type URL.

Comment: thanks for your contribution. Your answer is very instructive. I solved the problem

Comment: There are also protocols which typically don't correspond to a URI scheme at all, like DNS (port 43) and many URI schemes which are used for backend services like `ws:` for websockets which don't particularly need a dedicated host for users to earily discover. Many modern protocols just piggyback on HTTPS for transport, like Git's (though it can also use SSH).

Comment: DNS is port 53. 43 is WHOIS :)